# What causes an XP bonus after a race?

Tags: dragonvale

Sometimes after completing a race, winning, and spinning the wheel, I'll receive an XP bonus in addition to whatever prize I won randomly. What causes this to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My observation has been that the bonus is generated randomly, but that the worse your prize is, the higher % chance that you will get a bonus.  For a 1st place finish a 2500 or 2750 food prize are the ones that generate the bonus the most often for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you race:

- If you come first, you're most likely to get one.
- With a food reward, you may get gold.
- With a gold reward, you may get XP.